# what is the most simple and efficient way to return value from Runnables in Thread Pool Executor?

Tags: java, threadpool

I have created a `DataBaseManager` Class in my android app that manages all database operations for my app.

I have different methods to create,update, and retrieve value from  database.

I do it on a runnable and submit it to the Thread pool Executor.

In case, I have to return some value from this `Runnable`, how can I achieve it, I know about callbacks but it will be little cumbersome for me as the number of methods large.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: A `Runnable` doesn't return anything. Use `Callable`. That's its purpose.

Comment: Just it case it's not clear, use a `Callable<ReturnType>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to use [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)**: `Interface Callable<V>`

1. Like *Runnable*, It's instances are potentially executed by another thread.
2. But smarter then *Runnable*: Capable of returning result and checked Exception

Using it is as much simple as *Runnable*:

```
private final class MyTask extends Callable<T>{
  public T call(){
     T t;
    // your code
       return t;
    }
}
```

I am using `T` to represent a reference type e.g. `String`.

**Getting the result upon completion:**

- [**`using Future<V>`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):  A Future represents the result of an
  asynchronous computation. Methods are provided to check if the
  computation is complete, to wait for its completion. The result is
  retrieved using method *get()* when the computation has completed,
  blocking if necessary until it is ready.

  ```
    List<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<>(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      futures.add(pool.submit(new MyTask()));  
    }  

    T result;  
    for(Future<T> f: futures)
       result = f.get(); // get the result
  ```

  The disadvantages of above approach is that, if first task takes a
  long time to compute and all the other tasks ends before the first,
  the current thread cannot compute the result before the first task
  ends. Hence another solution would be to use *CompletionService*.
- [**`using CompletionService<V>`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html):  A service that decouples the
  production of new asynchronous tasks from the consumption of the
  results of completed tasks. Producers submit tasks for execution.
  Consumers take completed tasks and process their results in the order
  they complete. Using it is as simple as follows:

  ```
  CompletionService<T> pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<T>(threadPool);
  ```

  And then use *pool.take().get()* to read the returned result from
  callable instances:

  ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       pool.submit(new MyTask());
     }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        T result = pool.take().get();

     //your another code
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

the below is the sample code for using callable

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);     

            Future f1 =executorService1.submit(new callable());
            Future f2 =executorService1.submit(new callable());     
            System.out.println("f1 " + f1.get());
            System.out.println("f1 " + f2.get());

            executorService1.shutdown();
        }

    }


    class callable implements Callable<String> {
        public String call() {
             System.out.println(" Starting callable Asynchronous task" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
             try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(" Ending callable Asynchronous task" +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return Thread.currentThread().getName();
        }
    }
```